# Disable a button using d3 / jquery until the action is complete

Tags: jquery, d3.js

How do I disable a button until an action is complete? Here's how my code looks;

```
<audio id="audio">
<source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<button id="button">Play</button>
<script>
....
....
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

var onClick = function() {
audio.play(); 
d3.select('.svg')
.append('circle')
...
...
...
};

button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
....
....
</script>
```

I've tried the following but none of them seem to work;

```
$("#button").off();
d3.select("#button").attr('disabled', null);
$('#button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Why don't you add the event listener at the end of the action?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I've added it to the end. I don't want someone to click on the 'play' button when it is in action. The d3 'circle' append too gets affected when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the variety of [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) triggered by `<audio>` to get updates on the status of the audio element. One way might remove the click handler for the button once it gets clicked and re-register the handler when playing finishes, i.e. when the `ended` event is triggered.

```
var onClick = function() {
    // Remove the click handler when the button is clicked.
    button.removeEventListener('click');
    audio.play(); 
};

// Re-register the click handler once playback has finished.
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
}
```

Another approach might use a flag to keep track of the status of `<audio>`. This might be the most flexible solution because you can set the flag in various event handlers listening for all kinds of events (play, pause, ended, etc.):

```
var isPlaying = false;

audio.addEventListener("playing", function() {
    isPlaying = true;
}

audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    ifPlaying = false;
}

// Check the flag in the button's event handler.
var onClick = function() {
    // If this is playing, do nothing.
    if (isPlaying) return;

    audio.play(); 
};
```